# Definition of $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, axioms

In real number axioms, it is defined that there is $0$ such that $x+0=x$ for all $x.$ I was wondering an example is there any other algebraic structure than real numbers which satisfy the real number axioms other than $x+0=x$ but where $x\cdot 0=0\cdot x =0$ for all elements $x$.

This question popped on my mind when I was wondering why $0x=0$ is not an axiom. I know how to prove it from the other axioms but I'm not sure if $0x=0$ implies that $x+0=x$.

Comment: Look for *fields* on Wiki.

Comment: any other field

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you including the order axioms for the reals - which axioms do you want?

Comment: I'm including order axioms in the structure.

Comment: Your first question would depend on what "real number axioms" you take. Your second question would depend on exact axioms and formulations you choose. It is often the case that removing an axiom causes some apparently equivalent statements to become inequivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be interested in the notion of a [real closed field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field). Among the many properties is that all real closed fields are *elementarily equivalent* -- any statement you can make using only first-order logic and $+,-,\cdot,/,$ and $<$ is true in one real closed field if and only if it is true in *all* real closed fields.

In particular, $\mathbb{R}$ is a real closed field, and there are many other examples of such things as well, such as $\overline{\mathbb{Q}} \cap \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: His answer seems incomplete. You would have to use a construction or definition of $\mathbb{Q}$ that did not depend of zero. What is your construction/definition of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: In particular, since part of the definition of real closed field is that it be a field, the axiom $x + 0 = 0$ is already in place.

Comment: @MartianInvader: Your edit changes the meaning of the question as I read it. (I do not know if it changes the meaning as the OP meant it, though)

Comment: @Hurkyl Fair enough; the original question was pretty difficult to parse and had several possible interpretations. I chose one based mostly on the comment "I'm not sure if 0x=0 implies that x+0=x".  But if the OP can clarify, then of course we can edit it further.

Answer (score 3):

If you view the real numbers as an ordered field, then $\Bbb Q$ and any intermediate field between $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R$ as well. There are other ordered fields, much much larger than $\Bbb R$, too.

But you can also think of the real numbers as a field, without concern of the order, in which case *every* field has this property. That is to say, in every field $0+x=x=x+0$ and $0\cdot x=0\cdot x=0$. Examples for fields are $\Bbb C$, and even finite fields like $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$.

You can also remove *some* of the properties and view the real numbers as a ring, or a commutative ring, or a domain, or many other stronger or weaker types of rings. And in rings it holds that $0$ has these properties as well. However in an arbitrary ring not all elements have a multiplicative inverse, and sometimes the multiplication is not commutative, and sometimes other bad things happen as well.

Answer (score 0):

This does not really have anything to do with real numbers. This is a question about fields, or rather, rings.

A ring $(R, +, \cdot)$ is an abelian group $(R, +)$ with a multiplication $\cdot$ that is associative and compatible with the group structure, i.e. that it fulfills the distributive properties $x\cdot(y+z) = x\cdot y + x \cdot z$ and $(x+y)\cdot z = x\cdot z + y \cdot z$ for all $x, y, z \in R$.

From this automatically follows $0 \cdot x = 0$ as 
$$0 \cdot x = (0 + 0)\cdot x = 0 \cdot x + 0 \cdot x \Longrightarrow 0 = 0 \cdot x$$
This is why you do not need $0 \cdot x = 0$ as an axiom. It follows from the other axioms.

On the other hand, it does not make sense to not require $0 + x = x$, as you want that to have a well-formed addition.

As for the other axioms for the reals: You want $(R \setminus \{0\}, \cdot)$ to be an abelian group as well (i.e. to be a field), and you require that it is 1) complete and 2) archimedically ordered. Then you can show that there is only one such set (up to isomorphy).

Answer (score -4):

How are you going to establish an axion that  $0\cdot x=0$ where $x=\infty$? $0\cdot \infty$ is indeterminate.

Hence $0\cdot x=0\implies0+x=0$ isn't true $\forall x \in \Bbb R$

Comment: $\infty \notin \mathbb R$.